# How to allow only one message to appear when mouseover() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the code for my question. I have a check list and when I hover over the "take out the trash" the mouse over event works. However it duplicates every time I hover over "take out the task"

What I want is for a person to hover over "take out the trash" and the mouse over event to appear, but when I use mouseleave for it to disappear again, and not to duplicate every time I hover over it. The message should only appear once

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
      <div id="outer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="" />Take out the trash
    </label> 
  </div>
</li>

<li class="ui-state-default">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
         <div id="list2">
            <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" />Buy bread</label> 
          <div id="hidden1">
        Buy milk
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>


$( "#outer" ).mouseover(function() {
 $( "#hidden" ).show();
 });


  $("#outer").mouseleave(function(){
 $( "#hidden" ).hide();
 });


$( "list2" ).mouseover(function() {
$( "#hidden1" ).show();
});


 $("#list2").mouseleave(function(){
 $( "#hidden1" ).hide();

 });
```

Comment: Instead of appending have a hidden div there. Then when the user hovers, show it and when they leave hide it again

Comment: @Craicerjack how do you create a hidden div?

Comment: @Smith, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wra8Lzss/

Comment: You also could give a class to the appended div... Then on mouseleave, target that class to `remove()`. -- `$("outer").append("");` simply is doing nothing.

Comment: There is a missing `</div>` in your markup...

Comment: @sinisake is there any way to use your code to apply it to different items in the list. I have edited the code above to show you what I have. But it isnt working

Comment: Yes, you forgot '#'sign for id... and, yes, as mentioned, please fix markup, there are some errors....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hover Text</title>
    <style>
    .hidden-div {
      display: none;
    }

    .checkbox:hover .hidden-div {
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
       <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
           <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
           <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="" />Take out the trash
           <div class="hidden-div">This is the notes for this item</div>
         </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
       <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
           <img src="img/edit.png" id="edit" alt="edit list">
           <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="" />Make your Bed
           <div class="hidden-div">Fluff your pillow too.</div>
         </label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

This uses just CSS to hide and show the `hidden-div`.